# Unknown column 'settings_name' in 'where clause'

Tags: sql

При установке плагина `jOrange` на `webAsyst` выскакивает такое сообщение:

> Unknown column 'settings_name' in 'where clause'

Что значит этот `where clause`?
И как устранить эту ошибку?

B ниже `DELETE FROM JO_settings WHERE settings_name like('%JO_ARTICLES%')`

Comment: и ниже 
DELETE FROM `JO_settings` WHERE `settings_name` like('%JO_ARTICLES%')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В условиях отбора запроса (where) используется столбец (settings_name), которого либо нет в таблице, либо его имя написано с ошибками.

Comment: добавить этот столбец? Только в какую таблицу?
С разработчиками свзяаться пробовал. молчат..

Comment: Если возможно, найдите, где выполняется этот запрос (возможно, использовать поиск по контексту). Оттуда можно узнать имя таблицы, затем посмотреть в базе ее определение.
Но я думаю, что установка должна была все корректно сделать. Не возникали ли ошибки при установке? Может какие записи в журналах остались.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема с базой данных, а конкретно в поле одной из таблиц. Попробуйте скопировать текст ошибки в гугл транслэй и может чего поймете.